# Java Mail API call Server method

Tags: java, api, email

My question is how to call mail server method through Java? This method is called with JavaScript on the server.

The problem is that the Java Mail API cannot delete message from the server. I use `message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETE,true);` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but there is a java mail library available see here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

Comment: The problem is that the Java Mail API cannot delete message from the server. I use message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETE,true); but it doesn't work. I figured it out. With socket connection to the Mail server and send request DELE which delete the messages.

Comment: I found something here http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=17035. Are you closing your connection?

Comment: I saw this example more than one time. I have even try it and no I don't close the connection. I'm shure about this. With socket works fine for me.